# controller with this name is not registered in angularjs ngroute

Tags: angularjs, controller, ngroute

I am creating a web app in mvc-angularjs, I am using ngroute.

Angularjs controller in my layout with html code:

```
<div class="container body-content" ng-app="MyApp">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out</a>
    </div>

    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
</div>

<script>
    (function () {

        var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', "ngStorage"]);  

        app.controller('myctrllayout', function ($scope) {  

        });
    })();
 </script>
```

and this is my welcome page:

```
<div ng-controller="welcome">

</div>
<script>
    angular.module('MyApp',[]) 
    .controller('welcome', function ($scope) { 

    });
</script>
```

when I run the code I got the following error

> Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not
>   registered.
>
> The controller with the name 'welcome' is not registered.

when I change my app from `('MyApp',[])` to `('MyApp')`:

> Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
>   or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify
>   the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 5):

`angular.module` Can create a new module or retrieve an existing. This depends on the syntax you use.

This is also [referenced](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) on the **official angular documentation**.

e.g.

`angular.module('MyApp',[])` creates a new module because it includes the dependency injection array (as second parameter).

`angular.module('MyApp')` is a reference on the existing module because it does not include the dependency injection array.

In your case it creates a new module on the first block of code. So in the second block of code you need to retrieve it.

Possibly the problem would be solved if you change

`angular.module('MyApp',[])` to `angular.module('MyApp')` in the second block of code.

Comment: Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.


This was the error i was getting

Comment: Is this the error you get after you updated code from my answer ?

Comment: Also remove from the first block the declaration of `var app` so it will be: `angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', "ngStorage"]) 

.controller('myctrllayout', function ($scope) {  
            });`

Comment: i declared that on my layout page,